# Get max value from second table and sort the result set on with same by joining two tables

Tags: mysql

I'm stuck on a query.

I have the following table structure

table 1

```
+----+-------+
| cid |  name|
+----+-------+
|  1 | name1 |
|  2 | name2 |
|  3 | name3 |
|  4 | name4 |
|  5 | name5 |
+----+-------+
```

table 2

```
+----+-------+------+
| id | cid   | value|
+----+-------+------+
|  1 |    1  | 200  |
|  2 |    1  | 300  |
|  3 |    1  | 500  |
|  4 |    2  | 200  |
|  5 |    2  | 400  |
|  6 |    3  | 100  |
+----+-------+------+
```

I need a query to fetch the data with max value in descending order of the table 2. Table 1 and table 2 has a relation of one to many, so I need a result like

```
+----+-------+------+
| cid | name | value|
+----+-------+------+
|  1 |  name1| 500  |
|  2 |  name2| 400  |
|  3 |  name3| 100  |
|  4 |  name4| NULL |
|  5 |  name5| NULL |
+----+-------+------+
```

Comment: It would be nice to see what you actually have tried :)

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do this is with a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*,
       (select max(value)
        from table2 t2
        where t2.cid = t1.cid
       ) as maxvalue
from table1 t1
order by maxvalue desc, t1.cid;
```

Comment: Thank you so much friend its absolutely correct what i need :):)

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
select t1.cid,t1.name,max(t2.value) as value from Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 on t2.cid=t1.cid
group by t1.cid desc value desc;
```

Comment: Thank you so much friend its absolutely correct what i need :):)